# Audio file share on Facebook using my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, soundcloud

Am also having some problem with sharing audio/video,

I tried this code block to share audio file.

```
me = FbGraph::User.me(ACCESS_TOKEN)    
me.feed!(
        :message => 'Updating via FbGraph',
        :source => 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/derbywire_development/system/audios/21/original/ROJA.mp3?1376993284',
        :description => 'A Ruby wrapper for Facebook Graph API',
        :name => 'FbGraph',
        :type => 'mp3'
    )
```

Its sharing the post the but the player is not coming for me. its simply showing the link.

[image]

Can anyone help me out this problem?